# Can an empty line be present within the body of a HTTP response message?

Tags: python, http

For clarification, I am referring to the response body which comes after the status line, headers and one empty line in a HTTP response.
Context:
I am trying to make a HTTP webserver in python that can use CGI scripts to generate part of a response message. However, I am not sure what format each CGI script's output will be in. Some scripts may contain headers and/or a newline between the header and body, whilst some may not. The way I will handle the output of cgi scripts depends on the answer to the above question.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. The format of an HTTP response is headers, followed by a blank line, followed by the response body. The format of the response body itself is arbitrary: it can be pretty much anything.

Comment: @larsks , Yes I am asking whether the the response body (the last part of the HTTP response format) can contain an empty line. It is possible that the body can contain an empty line?

Comment: Yes of course it can -  an empty line definitely falls into @larsks “pretty much anything” that is covered by the entirety of the content length declared in the response headers

Comment: I mean, do "view source" on this page and you will see lots of blank lines that were included in the http response.

Comment: Just to be clear the blank line between headers and body is __required__ - it’s what tells the recipient of the response that the headers have finished, so this blank line __isn’t__ part of the body.